# Filling ng-model attribute with strings

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have this code below inside a form:

```
.col-xs-1(ng-repeat='n in num')
        .text-center {{n.day}}
        .text-center {{n.index}}
        select.form-control(ng-model='{{n.model}}' required)
            option(value='' disabled selected) Shift
            option(ng-repeat='s in shift' value='{{s.val}}') {{s.shift}}
```

Here is the controller code attached to the form:

```
var hari = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jumat', 'Sabtu']
var y = new Date().getFullYear()
var m = new Date().getMonth()+1
var days = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate()
$scope.num = []
for(var i = 1; i <= days; i++){
    var mdl = 'form.d_'+ i
    var d = hari[new Date(y, m, i-2).getDay()] // i-2 for the right index
    $scope.num.push({
        index: i,
        model: mdl,
        day: d
    })
}
```

I would like to insert the `n.model` string into the ng-model attribute. And what I've tried didn't work out. What would be the best approach to this?

**EDIT:** I've tried `ng-model='n.model'` and it doesn't work, nothing got through to `req.body` (ExpressJS) except other inputs.

**EDIT 2:** Ok, it seems that when I select an option it overwrites `n.model`. That's why it's not getting through. How do I prevent this?

**EDIT 3:** [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TEsnJUwKdAPtPLcBVbu6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the curlies from your ng-model:

```
select.form-control(ng-model='n.model' required)
```